# How to secure UPDATE action in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I would like to avoid UPDATE security problem in my multi-user CakePHP application. I'll illustrate it on this simple example. There is a simple edit method such this:

```
 public function edit($id)
    {

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {    
           $updated = $this->Template->save($this->request->data);    
           // Do some logic here...    
        }

        $this->request->data = $this->Template->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Template.id' => $id)));

    }
```

**Problem:** when somebody modifies POST data and change ID (`PK` of the record) CakePHP will modify record of another user. I would like to secure condition and update record that is defined by two conditions - its `PK` AND `user id` (owner, logged in user).

There is a model method `updateAll()` that accepts an array with `UPDATE ... WHERE` conditions but this method is not so easy to use as `save()` method, because it requires data array in different structure than `save()` method and I have to modify `$this->request->data` into appropriate structure and do escaping string values.

I had an idea to `SELECT` an appropriate record with two conditions (`PK` and `owner id`) before update is executed, but I don't like this because one more database operation.

**Is there some another method or workaround how to secure `UPDATE` operation in CakePHP applications?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just load the Security Component, like this:

CakePHP 3

```
use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class TemplatesController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Security');
    }
}
```

Read more here: [CakePHP Security - form tampering prevention](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/security.html#form-tampering-prevention)

CakePHP 2

```
<?php
class TemplateController extends AppController {

public $components = array('Security');

}
```

Read more here [CakePHP Security](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html)